# Access method of parent component from within slot

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to update a table component I've written a while ago for Vue projects. I'm trying to let the user define the columns using slots. However, these slots need data from the parent component, which I'm now providing via the slot-scope. Unfortunately this leads to a lot of unnecessary code, because the property from the slot-scope is simply passed on to the child component via props. I keep thinking that this can be achieved in a better and much nicer way. Do you have any suggestions for the code sample below?

**VueTable.vue**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <slot name="header" :sorting="sorting" :click-handler="clickHeader"></slot>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="let row of rows">
            <slot name="row" :row="row"></slot>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

export default {
    name: 'vue-table',

    methods: {
        .. 

        clickHeader(..) {
            ..
        },

        ..
    }
}
```

**Example.vue**

```
<vue-table>
    <template slot="header" slot-scope="{sorting, clickHandler}">
        <vue-table-header :sorting="sorting" @click="clickHandler" label="Naam" identifier="title"></vue-table-header>
        <vue-table-header :sorting="sorting" @click="clickHandler" label="Einddatum" identifier="end_date"></vue-table-header>
    </template>

    <template slot="row" slot-scope="{row}">
        <vue-table-column :row="row" property="title"></vue-table-column>
        <vue-table-column :row="row" property="description" type="custom">
            This is a custom table column, which uses multiple properties: {{ row.id }} has a description of: {{ row.description }}
        </vue-table-column>
        <vue-table-column :row="row" property="end_date" type="date"></vue-table-column>
    </template>
</vue-table>
```

The `vue-table-header` needs the sorting object and clickHandler to show which column is actively sorted and update it.

The `vue-table-column` has access to the row property, to be able to access other properties than just the one which is defined as 'property'.

**The *issue* I'm having with the example above is, that for each column, I need to pass the `row` again. And for each header, I need to pass the sorting properties and click handler to adjust the sorting.** I believe there's a much better solution for this :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is much you can do now without changing your design.

If there are more properties and more event handlers which need to be passed to a slot, it can be useful to group em up so they can be passed to components using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object)/[events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) object syntax

In table component:

```html
<slot name="header" :props="{ sorting: sorting, showGroupBy: showGroupBy } :on="{ sort: sortHandler, groupBy: groupByHandler }"></slot>
```

In template (using the table component):

```html
<v-table>
  <template v-slot:header="{ props, on }">
    <v-header v-bind="props" v-on="on" />
  </template>
</v-table>
```

This will work if `v-header` component expects props `sorting` a `showGroupBy` and can emit events `sort` and `groupBy`.

Generally tables are not easy. I think good inspiration for a design can be Vuetify's [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables). They do amazing things - providing default behavior which is sufficient in most cases and at the same time provide a way to customize on column/row level (by "item.item_name" slots for example). But it's only possible because they use render functions and no templates....